# whatsapp bluetooth call gets disrupted by 2nd incoming call

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluetooth, android-10

In Android 10, while talking to a person on Whatsapp using bluetooth headphones, I receive a standard call on the phone, and two bad things happen:

1. the sound of incoming call is bothering me for too long and too loud, as if it does not realise I'm using bluetooth headphones,
2. once the incoming call is not answered, I lose bluetooth connection in Whatsapp, namely it goes back to default phone speaker/mic.

(This situation could also be e.g. Whatsapp/Signal, or even perphaps the ongoing call being disrupted by the incoming one: in this case where is the priority set?)

Is this a bug of my phone/ROM, or is it standard?
Is there a way to have a better default behaviour, perhaps

1. only hear a low sound for incoming 2nd call while on bluetooth,
2. not get bluetooth disrupted and having to set it back by hand

in the Android options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is WhatsApp bug. 
You can click on Bluetooth icon to reconnect to your headphone again.
Hope this helps till it is fixed.